AWS Textract Too Slow
We are using AWS Textract to OCR PDFs. We don't use any of their advanced form/table detection, queries, etc. features. We only want to take a PDF (or PNG/JPEG), and get back a list of all "blocks" with coords that are numbers.
We are finding it to be too slow for our use case, sometimes taking up to 90 seconds for bigger PDFs (30+ pages).
AWS told us that:

Textract does not currently offer a premium tier for faster processing or dedicated capacity. The service operates on a shared infrastructure, and processing times can vary based on current demand and other factors.

What can we do that is relatively easy and ideally stays on AWS? I am considering hosting an open source OCR like Tesseract, or maybe splitting PDFs up into smaller requests to Textract, but wondering what others have had success with. Thanks.
